# How to connect via LAN without Wi-Fi or Ethernet

Tags: wifi

My internet is very, very messed up, and I have tried fixing it for weeks now. I have diagnosed it as unfixable.

It works on my neighbor's internet. I have two macs, and would like to know how to make LAN work without Wi-Fi or Ethernet. Is this even possible?

Comment: Connecting via LAN and connecting via the internet are two different things, I'm not sure what your asking. Why can't you use a router's wi-fi to lan your machines?

Comment: Maybe if you find a mod that supports play over Bluetooth...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  the user is asking how to set up the network area of a game. If we remove the game from the equation (eg. try doing this with alternate applications or even for basic communication), **we have the same problem**. As such, this is not a game related question as much as it is a network related question.

Comment: This would be better asked on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Also consider that if you agree this is not a minecraft question, there is no real use in editing out the Minecraft part. We dont take questions soley about WiFi in the first place.

Comment: @Timelord64 It doesn't hurt, and it will prevent it from distracting other users thinking they can answer a Minecraft question until it's decided to be closed.

Answer (score 6):

## You can't.

LAN is **Local Area Network**. If you can't connect to said local area network, you can't use it.<sup>1</sup>

In other terms: The name of the wifi for both the hoster and player (both macs I assume) needs to be the same (i.e. both connected to same modem)

I'm not sure if you can use the neighbor's wifi as a stand-in (see the footnote below). Worth a shot though. (assuming consent is given)

As @Tas also noted in the comments, connecting the computers directly should work (with an ethernet cable). However if they aren't connected to the internet, things like skins probably won't show up.

<sup>1: LAN is weird. In my experiences, it usually means the set of computers connected to the same modem. But it can also mean the set of computers connected to the same internet cable/antenna/magic-receiver-thingy. (what the modem connects to) But most likely it means your wifi network in this case.</sup>

Comment: A LAN can work without a modem: simply using a switch, router, or just straight up connecting the two computers together via a cable will work.

Comment: @Tas What kind of cable?

Comment: @ALX Ethernet cable

Comment: @SorinLascu I've tried that before, but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you plug your computer straight into the router with an Ethernet cable and everything works fine then your Internet connection is probably fine it's your WiFi that's messed up.

Assuming you've ruled out Ethernet because you can't run a line, there is another option: Ethernet Over Power aka Powerline aka [HomePlug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HomePlug) aka IEEE 1901. This uses your house's electrical wiring as a network line. You get two little boxes, one from your computer and one for your router. You plug them into a normal electrical socket, one near your computer and one near your router, then plug a normal Ethernet line into both of them. I use them for a gaming PC which is too far away from the WiFi router for a reliable connection. [TP-Link AV500s](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AWRUICG) go for about $40 a pair.

Note: this only works inside your own house. Though I suppose you could run an extension cord to your neighbor's house... you didn't get that idea from me.

Comment: Am I right in my assumption based off your comment that you do not believe thos is an ontopic question?

Comment: @Timelord64 Right. It should be migrated to superuser.com if possible. I assume answers will go with it.

Answer (score 0):

**Short** **Answer** : You cannot.
**Long** **Answer** : LAN (local area network) This term means anyone in close range or even connected to your Internet or Router can share files, printers, games, or any other applications. In order to *share* these types of categories you will need to have **Internet Access** with someone connected to your *router* allowing them to share these things.